# How to mask onUpdate()method when i add widget to the home screen?

Tags: android

How to mask onUpdate() method when i add widget to the home screen?

I have a widget that listens for user clicks..and i respond to it in onUpdate()..
The problem is,onUpdate() gets executed even when i add widgets to home screen.

```
  @Override
  public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
      int[] appWidgetIds) {

          if(flag)
                {
                Toast.makeText(context, "OFF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
flag=false;
                }
          else
                {
                Toast.makeText(context, "ON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
flag=true;
                }
}
```

Or how can i respond to user clicks if not in onUpdate() method?

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is,onUpdate() gets executed even when i add widgets to home screen.

That is not a "problem". `onUpdate()` needs to be called when the user adds your app widget to the home screen, so you can define what the app widget looks like.

> Or how can i respond to user clicks if not in onUpdate() method?

You are welcome to use whatever `PendingIntent` you wish with your buttons and such in your app widget. The `PendingIntent` does not have to route back to your `onUpdate()` method.

Also, I notice that your code snippet above assumes that there is a data member (or possibly a static data member) named `flag`. Bear in mind that your process will not always survive between app widget updates. Any sorts of "flags", therefore, need to be stored somewhere persistent: database, `SharedPreferences`, or some other form of file.